# How align a button below datatable if the values in datatable is increased

Tags: html, css, jsf, primefaces

I have created a datatable which is fetching values from the database and I can't increase the width of the table as scrollbar is added so the height can be increased but I wanted the button to be going down on basis of the table values once increased.
Please check the image attached in which the button is overlapping the values

[issue_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3TiI.png)

Below is the code which I have implemented for the datatable and button view

```
<p:dialog id="handOverIdsTable" widgetVar="dialogBox" modal="true" resizable="false"
                class="no-top-bottom-padding custom-dialog custom-dialog-hide-titlebar" height="400px" width="600px"
                style="background:white repeat-x scroll 0% 0% transparent;background-color:white; opacity: 1.0; ">
                <h:form>
         <p:dataTable id="dataTable1" var="dt1" value="#{flipBean.dataList}"
                     disabledSelection="#{flipBean.getSelectedItems}"
                     selection="#{flipBean.sysDetails}" rowKey="#{dt1.Id}"
                     rowSelectMode="checkbox" styleClass="table-border datatable-15-margin-left datatable-97-width"
                     style="margin-bottom:20px; height:350px;" paginator="true" rows="5" selectionPageOnly="false">
            <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:6%;vertical-align: top!important;" styleClass="custom-th custom-td" />
             <p:column headerText="Id">
                <h:outputText value="#{dt1.Id}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Weight">
                <h:outputText value="#{dt1.weight} #{dt1.weight_symbol}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Items">
                <h:outputText value="#{dt1.items}" />
            </p:column>
            
        </p:dataTable>
        <p:commandButton value="OK" id="finishBtn"
                                style="width: 160px; height: 37px; margin-left:200px; color:green"
                                onclick="#{flipBean.getSystemDetails(flipBean.sysDetails)};" update="flipForm:rqstPickUpOP, flipForm:itemTbl, messages"
                                oncomplete="PF('dialogBox').hide();"
                                 />
        </h:form>
        
            </p:dialog>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: try providing css classes instead of inline styling, and try providing the css stylesheet as the used css classes definitions here aren't provided. In any way, for your problem if you want fixed button, there are multiple approaches depending on your code, you could use `position: absolute` and make the parent or the table `position: relative`. Or you can use `poisiton: fixed` if you want to fix the button with respect to your viewport or `position: sticky` if you want the button to stick to its position after scrolling.